# Valor do DEG CSS

Tags: css

Quantos `px` equivale a `1deg`?

No caso, se tiver essa conversão. Ou no caso, como trabalhar com ele.

deg no caso, que usamos no transform do CSS.

Comment: 100px corresponde a 20.25 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconheço uma conversão de `deg` para `px`, até porque na minha cabeça não faz sentido. O `deg` ou degrees, é a medida para ângulos e degrees nada mais é do que graus em inglês. Ele é usado em transform especificamente para rotação em graus, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
.exemplo {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

O que está acontecendo é que o objeto de classe "exemplo" será rotacionado em 360 graus, ou seja, dará uma volta completa em sentido horário.

Comment: Ah, agora entendi. Não fazia ideia de que era graus, agora faz mais sentido kk, Obrigado!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Tranquilo! Boa sorte aí! :)